# Convert Apache rewrite conditions to Nginx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I've spent the last hour and a half attempting to get the following rewrite rules working properly in Nginx, but nothing I do will work properly! It either always ends up in an endless redirect loop or a 404.

The original .htaccess was this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css|php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1/

AcceptPathInfo On
```

I've set the correct FastCGI Path Info split parameter (`fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;`) but I just can't get the redirect rules / try_files rules working properly!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need classic index.php handler, but this is just part of config, maybe you need more configuration:

```
server {
...

  location /
  {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
    }
  }

  location ~* \.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ {
    expires 31d;
    access_log off;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass backend;
  }
...
}
```